# Which is faster? `list.pop(0)` vs `del list[0]`?

Tags: python, list, performance

Which list operation is faster?
`list.pop(0)` or `del list[0]`?

Comment: asymptotically , they are the same.

Comment: In `cpython`, `list.pop()` is a thin wrapper to `del list[]` with a few speedups (`list.pop(-1)` skips the `del` processing). With significantly sized lists, I doubt there is any difference. Except if you are popping off the end of the list, then `list.pop()` wins.

Comment: @tdelaney: `del list[-1]` may not have the fast path for `-1`, but it does bypass generic method dispatch (relatively expensive) in favor of skipping directly to the special purpose APIs available to keyword/syntax based operations, and it's asymptotically equivalent, so it doesn't make much difference. In my local tests, it seemed trivially slower for small `list`s, and trivially faster for large `list`s, but I suspect that's more about my laptop's CPU not holding the clock steady than it is about any measurable difference (that said, it's pretty stable on repeated runs...).

Comment: @ShadowRanger - that's a good point. I hadn't considered how the `del` got to the list delete function in the first place.

Comment: Use `list.pop()` only if you intend to collect the popped item. Readability of the code beats the nanosecond optimization.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer** Quick and dirty benchmark:

Using `IPython` on Python 3.7.6, it appears that **`del list[0]` is faster** as it takes only about 65% of the time spent by `list.pop(0)`.

Commands used:

```
## Baseline to be subtracted
%timeit lst = list(range(10))
# >> 230 ns ± 1.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

## list.pop(0) time taken
%timeit lst = list(range(10)); lst.pop(0)
# >> 281 ns ± 0.926 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

## del list[0] time taken
%timeit lst = list(range(10)); del lst[0]
# >> 263 ns ± 1.11 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

(263-230)/(281-230) = 33/51 = 65%

Comment: "This is expected as it doesn't need to return a value." That doesn't really explain it. Likely, this is merely the method resolution overhead. Also, the performance is going to depend on the size of the list, as the list grows, this difference is going to shrink to be negligible

Comment: IOW, this is a very misleading benchmark. For most practical purposes, they are the same. Try it with `range(1000)` then `range(10000)`

Comment: The added cost of returning a value is just incrementing the reference counter... which is decremented again in the caller's code eventually.

Comment: @tdelaney: Doesn't need to increment the reference counter even; it just transfers ownership of that reference from the `list` to the caller. So it's a decrement in `del`, or a decrement when the caller doesn't assign it and it gets popped off the stack.

Comment: @ShadowRanger - I peeked at the source... it increments the ref count so make up for the decref `list_ass_slice` (which is the implementation for `del`) is about to do. The special case is `pop(-1)` where it skips del processing.

Comment: Side-note: Why even assign the result of `pop`? That's just more bytecode to execute that you don't need if you're testing using `pop` instead of `del` when you don't need the returned value.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga This operation may be significant when done repeatedly in a loop. e.g. https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/cc7051dc592802f501e8a6f71f8fb3cf9de95dc9/create_pretraining_data.py#L431   Hence my quick and dirty benchmark.

Comment: @RyanY I am not sure what that link is supposed to demonstrate. In that context you linked there is so much more micro-optimization you can do it is not really significant. And once the list grows to not even a particularly large size, the difference disappears, because the runtime is dominated by internal re-allocation

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sure, agree with you fully: as the list grows, a single pop() operation is negligible, but not if you do multiple pop()s in a loop. My link shows a `while True` loop where an item is removed one-by-one until `break`. This is the pt I'm trying to make. That's all. :)

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks. Noted on that. Though there doesn't seem to be any noticeable difference after removing the throwaway assignment to "_".